# Tables,indexes and constraints in postgres are getting auto deleted with Strapi

Tags: postgresql, strapi

I am developing an App with Postgres DB with Strapi.
I am using strapi as an api service.
I intend to use the same db for a separate service as well.

However, when I try to create a new constraint,index or table in my postgresDB it gets deleted automatically in some time.

Comment: One reason could be because when `strapi` server starts up, it tries to map the models with the db tables. If anything is different from what's specified in the model settings, it will alter that and match it with the requirements of the model files. I don't really think you should be modifying the tables directly in case of a headless cms like `strapi`.

Answer (score 0):

**Well 2 things actually:**

1. For creation of new tables, needless to say, you'll need to create
   it's `model` & `model.settings` files
2. For creation of indexes, you can alter the schema while the `NodeJS` is bootstrapping `Strapi`. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/9913#issuecomment-811014560) link.

```js
// ./config/functions/bootstrap.js

module.exports = () => {
  const knex = strapi.connections.default;
  await knex.schema.alterTable('tableName', async t => {
    // you might need to check the index existence first
    
    // single column indexes
    t.index('columnName', 'index_name');
    // for multi column indexes
    t.index(['colA', 'colB'], 'index_name');
  })
}
```